# Growth of a sequence

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Let
$$a_n=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi}^{ \frac{3\pi}{2}+3n\pi}\frac{\cos{t}} {t} dt$$

How to show that  $\left(a_{2n}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ is increasing (strictly) and $\left(a_{2n+1}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ is decreasing (strictly)?

I've tried transforming it a bit to :
$$a_n = \left(-1\right)^n\ \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\int_{\frac{\pi} {2}+2i\pi}^ {\frac{\pi} {2}+2(i+1)\pi}\cos{u} \left(\frac{1}{u+n\pi}- \frac{1}{u+(n+1)\pi} \right)du \right)+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos{u}}{u+3n\pi}du\right) $$
And calculated $a_{2(n+1)} - a_{2n} $ but I can't get further (I don't succeed in showing that this is $>0$)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use that
$$ |\cos(x)|=|\cos(x+\pi)| $$
for any $x$, while
$$ 0<\frac{1}{t+\pi}<\frac{1}{t} $$
for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Where's your hate Jack? You should use it. it's funny. (+1) ^^

Comment: I'm not sure how does this help? Some terms of the difference are positive and others positive :/ (I'm probably missing something obvious?)